# Is envy a theme or a motif?

Tags: meaning

I'm writing about a film - one of the events in the film is that I'm reminded of envy between two characters.

Towards the end this re-appears.

Which one is best? :

With the previous motif of envy between the men,

With the previous theme of envy between the men,

Comment: Would be nice if you looked up the meanings of the two words in a good dictionary and include the results of your research in the question. Else the Q may stand the risk of getting closed as GR.

Answer (score 2):

Motif and Theme are not quite synonyms. I like [this explanation](http://ed101.bu.edu/StudentDoc/Archives/ED101fa09/sfaustin/ThemevMotif.html):

> *Theme* is the main idea or message of the work. ...intended to teach a lesson or moral.
>   *Motif* is a recurring object or idea in a work. A motif can also be something abstract, such as an emotion or quality...

In summary both may imply something recurring as a work progresses, most obviously in symphonic music: *theme* implies the main idea, *motif* a subsidiary idea, possibly related to an overall theme.

Hence which to use depends on the significance of **envy** in your script. From your brief description I suspect that you should use *motif* as infer that envy is not the primary focus of your film.

Comment: Good find, but your conclusion shows that you need to re-read the cited reference.

Comment: Kris, I've explained why I think the use of Motif is appropriate in this instance. I believe this to be consistent with the cited article.

Comment: Sorry but no, your understanding of the difference is missing something important there. :)

Comment: Go on, tell me ... I just don't see it. To quote: A theme is the main, overall idea or lesson the author is trying to teach in his book. A motif is a smaller idea that we see come up again and again in the book. A motif can be used to help develop the theme.

Comment: Point #1. "theme is the main, overall idea" | "motif ... come up again and again" (recurrent)  Point #2. "Theme implies the main idea, Motif a subsidiary idea" -- Get the drift?

Comment: But wait. The OP is expected to make some effort of their own in the first place. :)

Comment: Don't much care about OP duties, care about coming to a good conclusion. So as the question (perhaps) implies only two occurrences of "envy" this is not recurring again and again and hence not a motif? Does that same stricture apply to themes? If envy is not the main idea, hence not a the theme, and envy does not occur often enough to be a motif, then it's a ...?

Comment: @djna - good answer, good find. +1. I added relevant definitions from your source and reformatted. If you feel these take away from your answer, please feel free to roll back. You are correct in your interpretation. If I could offer (obvious) examples: if one were writing a piece with a message of, say, how depression distorts perception, and the author uses a black-eyed dog as a recurring object, those would represent the theme and the motif, respectively.

Comment: +1 From what little information OP has provided (Towards the end *envy* between two characters re-appears) motif would also be my choice.

Comment: The film is The Fly (1986). I wanted to emphasize the use of Envy which seems to foreshadow the final conflict between two men, to help describe how the story elements come together using psychological undertones. (Without mentioning the psychology, calling it a 'motif' becomes invalid.)

The use of descriptors is abstract, and envy plays a much smaller psychological role in the film than anything else (I also cover The Hero's Journey aspects for example). So 'motif' I guess is very much unsuitable too.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with 'motif' - 'theme' sounds romantic.

Comment: Basing your answer on something better than what "sounds" good to you, like a definition or a reference from a site on literary devices, would make this a helpful answer. The [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) provides guidance on how to use this site.